# How to call a void with Graphics as parameter

Tags: java

```
public void Filler(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(Height, Width, 12, 12);
}
```

How can I call the `Filler` `void` because apparently
it doesn't want to let me do just `Filler();`?

Comment: What do you mean call it "void"?  You need to pass in a Graphics object.  How else do you expect this method to call setColor and drawRect on it?

Comment: The void merely means that this method doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the method you're trying to call

```
public void Filler(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(Height, Width, 12, 12);

}
```

Notice where it says `(Graphics g)`?
These are called parameters and it basically means that the method you want to call **requires** you to pass it a value for that parameter.

In this case, in order to call your method you must pass it a Graphics object.

So you would call it like this:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics(); // creating this object also might require arguments to be passed!!
filler(g);
```

You cannot just do filler(); because that means you are passing it no values.